# How can I get an array of strings as the submitted value for react-final-form using react-select?

Tags: react-select, react-final-form

I'm trying to get a react-select's multi-select component to submit the selected values as an array of strings but it's coming out as an array of {label, value} objects.

The structure of the objects I will be passing into react-select via react-final-form's Field component is like this:

```
[
{ val: "first-value", display: "First Value" }, 
{ val: "second-value", display: "Second Value" }, 
{val: "third-value", display: "Third Value"
];
```

Passing the prop `getOptionLabel={option => option.display}` is able to change the option labels to the display key given by the objects.

However doing the same thing for `getOptionValue` still gives me the entire `{val, display}` object when submitted. e.g. selecting the first item and submitting the form would get me `[{val: "first-value", display: "First Value" }]` when I only want `["first-value"]`

I'm not too sure if it's something I need to solve on react-final-form or on react-select

```
import React from "react";
import { Field } from "react-final-form";
import { Form } from "react-final-form";
import Select from "react-select";

const data = [{ val: "1", display: "123" }, { val: "2", display: "321" }];
const Test2: React.FC<any> = () => {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
      showErrorModal={showErrorModal}
      setShowErrorModal={setShowErrorModal}
    >
      {() => (
        <>
          <Field
            name="test"
            component={MultiSelect}
            label={"Multi Select test"}
            placeholder="Please Select..."
            options={data}
            getOptionLabel={option => `${option.display}`}
            getOptionValue={option => `${option.val}`}
          />
          <SubmitButton btnTxt="next" />
        </>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Test2;
```

When submitting, the message I get on the console is

```
[{"val": "1", "display": "123"}, {"val": "2", "display": "321"}]
```

whereas the result I'm hoping for is 
`["1","2"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getOptionLabel` & `getOptionValue` are only for viewing purpose.

When we get the selected value, it will give you the complete `object` as we provided array of object to `options`.

So the result of,

```
onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
```

is correct, which is `[{"val": "1", "display": "123"}, {"val": "2", "display": "321"}]`

You need to further work on this result to get your desired result as,

```
onSubmit={values => console.log(values.map(data=>data.val))}
```